# Dark Shaman vs Monsterslayer Shield

Tags: champions-of-midgard

In *Champions of Midgard*, I've run into a bit of an "unstoppable force vs immovable object" issue.

From *The Dark Mountains* expansion, there's a monster card called Dark Shaman that has the special ability: "Shields block no damage against this monster".

From the *Valhalla* expansion, there's a card you can get called Monsterslayer Shield that: "Blocks all damage when fighting monsters".

When fighting the Dark Shaman, I rolled a shield. What should the end result be? I can think of three possibilities:

1. Dark Shaman trumps Monsterslayer Shield
2. Monsterslayer Shield trumps Dark Shaman
3. They cancel each other out, and shields work as normal

There's rationale for each of these outcomes. For the first, because it says shields block no damage, it might beat the shield. However, for the second, because the shield uses the same phrasing in reverse, that it blocks all damage, it wouldn't qualify as a normal shield and thus would block (especially since shield odds are already so low, and the card is rather unique). Lastly, because they use the opposite phraseology, you could easily say that they just cancel each other out (seems the most balanced to me).

The rules don't clear this situation up. Has anyone encountered this before, and what is the consensus on how to resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In situations like this, games generally favour effects that add restrictions over effects that enable. ("Can't trumps can", as *Magic: The Gathering* players paraphrase the second Golden Rule of that game.)

It's not very clear from the wording which effect adds a restriction until we rephrase them in terms of damage: "*Damage from Dark Shaman can't be blocked by shields*" vs "*Monsterslayer Shield can block any amount of damage*". This makes Dark Shaman's ability the winner.

In short, it doesn't matter how much damage Monsterslayer Shield can block because it doesn't block any.

Keep in mind I have never played the game, but your question has been asked on Board Game Geek before, and all three posted opinions [concur](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1818102/monsterslayer-shield-vs-dark-shaman) .